# Ajax function call not working second time

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Need help to resolve ajax call issue
    In my view page ( working on codeigniter), there is a dropdown and a div 
    section. Based on dropdown value, data will get change in div section. I am 
    using ajax call ( to call method in controller) to upload data in div tag on 
    dropdown change event. Ajax call working fine on first change event of 
    dropdown but when i select value for second time in dropdown, ajax function 
    call is not working ( second select and so on).
    My code is:
    VIEW PAGE =>

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
 $("body").on('change','#assettype_id',function(e){  // "assettype_id" is 
                                                       dropdown id
  //e.preventDefault();   
   var categoryval = $('#assettype_id :selected').val();                         
   $.ajax({   
              type: 'POST',  
              cache: false,  
              url: 'http://my_path/index.php/assetcontroller/assignpc/'+ categoryval,  // Based on "categoryval" data will change in div tag  
              dataType: 'html',  
              success: function(data) {  
              $( "#result" ).load( "http://my_path/index.php/assetcontroller/assignpc/"+ categoryval);  // "result" is div tag id  
              $( "#result" ).html(categoryval);   
 },  
});  
    return false;  
  });  
 });
```

Why ajax call is not working in dropdown 'second time' change event?

Comment: should be like this $( "#assettype_id" ).on( "change", function() {
  
});

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried as you suggested but function is calling only for first change event. I searched around it and someone said that it happens due to URL cache so i added cache: false in ajax call but code is still not working for dropdown's second event change

Comment: Check console for error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `.on('change')` event into a function, so it can be called anytime later.

That's because once you have added new html output through Ajax, this html doesn't yet know about your change event!

So the function `my_change_event()` needs to be re-called, once your Ajax output has been added to DOM with your `$( "#result" ).load()`

something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   my_change_event();        
});

function my_change_event(){
   $( "#assettype_id" ).on( "change", function() { 
       $.ajax({   
          type: 'POST',  
          cache: false,  
          url: your_url,  
          success: function(data) {  
              // do something with data
              // html output
              my_change_event();
          } 
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do i need to call my_change_event() funcation separately? or it will get call automatically when dropdown event get change?

Comment: When i load view in new window, data is showing perfectly means dropdown second change (and so on) event is firing but when trying to  load data in div tag data is not loading. Why it is happening?.

Comment: $( "#result" ).load( "my_path/index.php/assetcontroller/assignpc/"+ categoryval);                                                                                         // this code is not working but next code is working - window.location.href="my_path/index.php/assetcontrolle r/assignpc/"+ categoryval;

Comment: Well my simple purpose is to change view page data based on dropdown value. If there is any other way do it? please suggest me..Thanks

Comment: Can any one help me on this?Thanks in advance